# MPLAB 8.9 won't launch

Tags: microcontroller, pic, mplab

I am running windows 7 professional 64-bit and up until this week was running MPLAB 8.92 IDE.  Now I get a brief look at the splash screen and the IDE refuses to launch.  I downloaded and ran the latest version of MPLAB X and it runs, but doesn't like legacy projects with "spaces or odd characters" in the pathname.  Has anyone else had this problem?  I have tried the normal sources - Microchip forums, Googling, etc, and although there are examples, none of the solutions have worked.  I have tried uninstalling and re-installing, running as administrator, using the -noswitch option.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 8.92 works fine for me under Win7 pro, but it asks for permission to make changes every time it starts unless you run as administrator. Make sure nothing is popping up on a nonexistent 2nd screen or something like that.

Comment: This is a better fit at SuperUser, since it's a Win7 application problem and not specifically EE.

Comment: Have you tried building the project under MPLAB X despite the "spaces or odd characters" warning? I've had that warning as well several times but it hasn't caused any apparent problems.

Comment: @AdamLawrence Technically, yes, but the OP will get only generic answers there, because none of the SU users have MPLAB X. Problems specific to EE-related software should be addressed here.

Comment: @SpheroPefhany Thanks for the suggestion.  "Run as Administrator" makes no difference.  I get a brief look at the splash screen, then it is gone.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Thanks - I am hoping someone out there has had this problem (and solved it).

Comment: John- is the program MPLAB.exe still running in task manager after the splash screen disappears? Did you check my suggestion about phantom screens? And did you do a re-install deleting all the files, directories and perhaps registry entries, if you're comfortable with the latter?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I am an SU user and I have MPLAB X...

Comment: @SpheroPefhany Thanks again for your help.  Mplab is not running in task manager nor any microchip process.  Yesterday I unistalled and removed all files and registry entries containing the string "mplab" in the filename or registry entry.  I need your help for phantom screens - I'm not sure how I would find them but there is no indication on my taskbar that there is anything running.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead with MPLABX is it just a path warning you've got? As mentioned above I've had that several times and it doesn't seem to cause any actual problems or do you get a hard error when trying to compile or it refuses to load?

Comment: @PeterJ Will not build and when I remove the spaces I get "No rule to make target `.build-conf'. Stop".  I probably have a learning curve on MPLAB X

Comment: @JohnBirckhead That makes it sound like it can't find a source file to compile an included module, it might be worth checking the project and make sure the project includes all the source files needed. I vaguely recall something similar with an old project and had to add some things under the project options / XC8 compiler (or what you're using) under the include directories that included the directories for the source for any additional libraries used.

Answer (score 6):

OK - found a result by desperation. In the MPLAB IDE\Utilities folder there is an executable called "SetDefaultMPLABStartup.exe."  After running it the problem went away.  Even a blind squirrel finds an acorn sometimes.

Comment: Thank you. The SetDefaultMPLABStartup app worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue for me too.